# The selenium webdriver always pickup the second result from google search suggestion

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Use below simple test code but selenium always like to choose second google suggestion result as the search text:

For example:

I input "Selenium", google will give suggestion list like below:

Selenium
Selenium WebDriver

Then webdriver will always pick up "Selenium WebDriver". But I used webdriver to sendKeys as "Selenium".

Is it a bug to webdriver?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLitianyiNewsIsExisting() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        inputField.sendKeys("selenium");
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).submit();

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "picks up the 2nd" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: updated more detail in description. @MarkRowlands

Comment: But google always gives a list of suggestions based on what was input. Do you mean that when you `submit` the form it is returning results for "selenium tutorial" rather than "selenium"?

Comment: yes. Mark, you got it. WebDriver actually submitted "selenium tutorial" into google when I used sendKeys("selenium").

Comment: One thing you need to remember is that google's website updates itself 'on the fly' as you enter a search term. What happens if you try `driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).submit()` - you may have to wait for that button to appear first though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure googles immediate results are bugging you here. Once you are halfway typing your query, Google will start showing you the results already and the "btnK" button will no longer be visible. Try this in stead:

```
@Test
public void testLitianyiNewsIsExisting() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        inputField.sendKeys("selenium");
        inputField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

Comment: Thanks joostschouten. You are correct, i'll accept your answer. Also thanks Mark's valuable analysis.